# Whitelist php script in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, octobercms

I'm trying all day to make this work and I can't make get it to work.
I'm using October CMS, which generates following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(form/contact.php)($|/) - [L]
##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
##
# RewriteBase /

##
## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/form/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/new/.*

##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
##RewriteRule !^contact.php contact.php [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I also have contact.php file, located in /form/ directory. What I want, is to allow contact.php to by executed when using POST. With wordpress or joomla I did not encounter such a problems. 
Also, is there a good tutorial for learning htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Add line to the section titled `White listed folders` above the final line with `RewriteRule`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !your-file\.php`

Comment out the section with title `Block all PHP files, except index`

Answer (score 0):

work this? I add condition when is filename contact.php. Here is tutorial to rewrite: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^contact.php$ ## this is new condition
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, unfortunately it seems not to be working - I still receive 403 error, when trying to either go directly throught browser or by POST from contact form :/

Comment: And if you remove complete "## Block all PHP files, except index" then work it?

Comment: Or add this (before ## Block all PHP files, except index") :

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^contact.php$
RewriteRule ^contact.php contact.php [L,NC]